# How can I export the tcp data from some packets I have captured?

Tags: regex, perl, wireshark

I have captured some application data in wireshark, (FIX messages) , and I am wondering if there is a way to export just the tcp data layer of each packet into a separate file, one row/line per packet.

I thought there used to be a function called tcp.data but this doesn't seem to exist in the version of wireshark I'm using (v1.10.1).

I had been planning on adding an extra column in Wireshark preferences, and setting it to type "custom" then putting tcp.data into the field.   Then exporting this column to a text file.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

PS. the other idea i had was to write a script to parse the capture file and effectively chop off the leading headers in front of the tcp layer data, but this will take some time - hopefully a way exists already to do this within wireshark itself.

---

**UPDATE 1:**
Extending Isaac's solution, I have come up with the following, however this is actually printing the entire tcp segment, not just the data from within the segment.  I've also tried tcp.segment_data but this also results in the same issue where more than the tcp data payload is getting outputted.  Unfortunately, at the moment the best option looks like manually parsing the pcap file.  Does anyone else have any suggestions, or perhaps spot what I've got wrong in the tshark command syntax?

```
tshark -r capture_chopped.pcap -c4 -2 -R "(tcp.len > 0)" -T fields -d tcp.port==2634,echo -e tcp.segment -w - > output.2
```

---

**UPDATE 2 - ISSUE RESOLVED:**
I found that every option with tshark didn't provide the entire info I needed, so I went with creating my own Perl script to fish out the FIX message strings from the pcap file directly.  The Perl script is included below in case it is helpful to anyone else in a similar situation with a PCAP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that creating a perl script to parse the PCAP file was sufficient for my needs - mainly due the other options of using tshark would have still needed some extra cleanup / manipulation (eg. converting the HEX into binary) so the script seemed like the best approach to me.

The perl script is included here in case it is useful for anyone else.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = shift || die "must give input pcap file as argument here. \n";

my $out_file = 'fix_output.txt';

open (my $out_fh, ">", $out_file) || die "error opening output file: [$out_file]. $! \n";
open (my $in_fh , "<", $in_file) || die "error opening input file: [$in_file]. $! \n";

my $pcap_blob = do {
    local $/ = undef;
    <$in_fh>;
};

my @FIX_strings = $pcap_blob =~ m/(8=FIX\.4\.0.*10=\d\d\d)/g;

print "found " . scalar @FIX_strings . " FIX messages\n";

for (@FIX_strings){
    print {$out_fh} $_ , "\n";
}
print "finished writing FIX messages to $out_file\n";

close $out_fh;
close $in_fh;

print "all done\n";
exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a script, you can use the built-in wireshark tool called tshark. It is usually located at: c:\Program Files\Wireshark if you installed wireshark in the default folder.

Then you use the following command line and it will do the trick:

```
tshark -r c:\captures\your_file.cap -R "(tcp.len > 0)" -T fields -d tcp.port=3868,echo -e echo.data
```

Few things to note about the above:

1. It filters tcp packets that have no payload, remove it if you want to identify the empty ones
2. It assumes you know the protocol port that your file contain which is usually a reasonable assumption. In the above 3868, replace it with the protocol you are using.

Then redirect the output to a file and you are done.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - however this is only outputing the tcp data as hex.  Is it possible to modify it to only output tcp data in binary format?